# fetch the data from clob datatype field

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to fetch a data from clob column but i can fetch the charactors but some unwanted data also coming in result which.
How to define end charactor while fetching from clob

Here is my sql query :

```
select substr(to_char(work_request_details),
              instr(to_char(work_request_details),
                    '"CompanyNumber":"') + 17) Company_Number
from work_request;
```

**Output :** 12"}

**Desired OutPut :** 12

How to take values only before " and remove "}

CLOB data :

```
{"TokenNumber":"","AccountLastFour":"0899","AccountName":"Test Account","ProgramName":"","PAName":"","HierachyId":"","SameAsCaller":"No","ContactName":null,"PhoneNumber":"(256) 225-9491","CallerAuthenticated":"No","ReasonsForCall":["New/ Change","PA Fe Waive","Add Change","Card Funding","SmartData assistance/access","CMS Alerts","Infospan"],"IsComplaint":true,"Complaints":["The customer claims a regulatory violation or violation of law.","The complaint involves potential consumer harm.","Resolution requires actions for which the colleague and/or their department is not able or capable of providing."],"AdditionalComments":"","CallResultedInCustomerComplaint":"Yes","IssueDescription":"","IssueWasResolved":"No","ReasonIssueNotResolved":"","SupervisorEscalationName":"","SubmittingDepartment":"Fraud Analyst","WorkRequestFormId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","SubmittedBy":"Lash, Mendi (mendilashcorpCB)","SubmitterEmail":"mendi.lash2@dxc.com","SubmitterPhoneNumber":null,"DateSubmitted":"\/Date(1653329078111)\/","CorpId":"CB","CompanyNumber":"12"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get substring with REGEXP\_SUBSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263157/get-substring-with-regexp-substr)

Comment: Note that work_request_details is a _column_, not a field.

Comment: You've told it where to start the substr, but not how long it should be, so it will get all of the string after that point. Which is nothing to do with it being a CLOB really. But this looks like it might be JSON - unless you're on an old version, why not process it as JSON with built-in functions, rather than using plain string manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat it as a string (instead of json), according to what your sql returned, it looks like you want a number from last value ( ends with '"}' ). If so, you can REPLACE '"}' with '':

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (   
            Select '{"CompanyCodeId": "C_1", "CompanyName": "Name for C_1", "CompanyNumber": "12"}' "TXT" From Dual Union All
            Select '{"CompanyCodeId": "C_2", "CompanyName": "Name for C_2", "CompanyNumber": "13"}' "TXT" From Dual Union All
            Select '{"CompanyCodeId": "C_3", "CompanyName": "Name for C_3", "CompanyNumber": "14"}' "TXT" From Dual 
        )
Select 
    REPLACE(  SubStr( TXT, InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber": "') + Length('"CompanyNumber": "')  ), '"}', '' ) "CO_NUMBER"
From
    tbl

CO_NUMBER  
-----------
12         
13         
14
```

If you can (and if it is json)  it's better to use [json functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/function-JSON_VALUE.html) to get your data.

If it is not the last value (something else aftter) then you should find the first " after the number and take what is before that ". Here is the code:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (   
            Select '{"CompanyCodeId": "C_1", "CompanyName": "Name for C_1", "CompanyNumber": "12", "SomethingElse": "AAA"}' "TXT" From Dual Union All
            Select '{"CompanyCodeId": "C_2", "CompanyName": "Name for C_2", "CompanyNumber": "13", "SomethingElse": "BBB"}' "TXT" From Dual Union All
            Select '{"CompanyCodeId": "C_3", "CompanyName": "Name for C_3", "CompanyNumber": "14", "SomethingElse": "BBB"}' "TXT" From Dual 
        )
Select 
    SubStr( TXT, 
            InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber": "') + Length('"CompanyNumber": "'),
            INSTR(  TXT, '"', InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber": "') + Length('"CompanyNumber": "'), 1  ) - (InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber": "') + Length('"CompanyNumber": "'))
          ) "CO_NUMBER"
From
    tbl
 
 CO_NUMBER   
-------------
12           
13         
14
```

If it is a large CLOB then use DBMS_LOB.SubStr() but read the docs as the parameters for starting position and length of chars to fetch switched positions compared to regular SubStr() function....
**Addition** (CLOB)
Created table A_TBL(ID Number(6), TXT CLOB) And inserted into TXT column the same sample data as above. The code using DBMS_LOB Package functions looks like here:

```sql
Select  ID,
        DBMS_LOB.SubStr( TXT, 
            DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"', DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber": "') + Length('"CompanyNumber": "'), 1  ) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber": "') + Length('"CompanyNumber": "')),
            DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber": "') + Length('"CompanyNumber": "')
          ) "CO_NUMBER"
From
    A_TBL


        ID CO_NUMBER   
---------- ------------
         1 12          
         2 13          
         3 14
```

When there is no blank spaces between key and value (in your clob data) then the code is like here:

```sql
Select  ID,
        DBMS_LOB.SubStr( TXT, 
            DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"', DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"'), 1  ) - (DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')),
            DBMS_LOB.InStr(TXT, '"CompanyNumber":"') + Length('"CompanyNumber":"')
          ) "CO_NUMBER"
From
    A_TBL

        ID CO_NUMBER   
---------- ------------
         1 12
```

Comment: actually not end with } , i need to fetch end with " , because in some of cases after " and before } there are some texts which not belongs CompanyNumber

Comment: its not json, its CLOB data

Comment: i tried but your output is giving in clob, i need to output in string like my current code

Comment: @VimalSingh Depending on size of the clob you should either use dbms_lob package functions (SUBSTR / INSTR) or convert the clob data to varchar and use functions as in the answer. I don't havae your data and can't replicate it. Just proposed a way to extract something from string.

Comment: @VimalSingh Just posted the code that uses  DBMS_LOB package functions.

Comment: its giving the wrong values from clob column and for each row different different column data , not Company Number.

Comment: @VimalSingh Sorry, but this last code is tested against  clob column in a table as described in Addition and it works as presented with the given sample data. Are you sure you implemented it in the right way against your data. Could it be something with spaces (blanks) in the data or in the code !?

Comment: let me paste the clob data in question

Comment: I have added the clob data in question.

Comment: @VimalSingh There is no blanks between key and value in your clob. I posted the last SQL with the correction everywhere with string '"CompanyNumber": "' the blank space between : and " is removed and now it is '"CompanyNumber":"'  - and it works with your CLOB. Some other possible issues could be with capital and small letters. The string that is searched must be the same.